# Cannot fill the fields on a site automatically using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, mozilla

Please help me to fill any field on the site: https://www.easytransfer.kz/.

I'm using `Python 2.7`.
Already tried to add a delay to the script.

The script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.implicitly_wait(60) # seconds
browser.get('https://www.easytransfer.kz/')

user1 = browser.find_element_by_name("pan1")
user1.send_keys("5307")
```

Comment: You need to [wait until the element is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504839/how-do-i-use-seleniums-wait)

Answer (score 0):

As per site `https://www.easytransfer.kz/` the intended fields are within an `<iframe>`. So you have **switch_to** the `<iframe>` first then lookout for the elements as follows :

```
driver.get('https://www.easytransfer.kz/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://payment.processinggmbh.ch/CNPConsumerWebsite/BACardToCard']")))
user1 = driver.find_element_by_name("pan1")
user1.send_keys("5307")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Goop point re iframe. I've tired but the IDLE shows me the error "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"

Comment: @DmitriySkubriyev Updated my Answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help! It works! ;)